# JS select input by type and name

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have this HTML markup:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" class="stat" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" value="">

<input type="text" name="name2" class="stat" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" value="">

<input type="text" name="namei" class="stat" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="namei" value="">

where i = 1,2,3, ... n
```

**Q:** How to select checkbox with name2 ?

Is this correct way ?

```
$('input[name="name2"]').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("disabled");
```

Comment: try input[name="nam2"][type="checkbox"].

Comment: $('input[name="name2"]').find will find the dedeceends, actually $('input[name="name2"]').filter(..) is ok

Comment: "Is this correct?", not tested yet?

Comment: @wared tested, but with bad result

Comment: So, this is not correct ;)

Comment: That said, I wonder why using two attributes in your query, only the first one might be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple attribute selectors at the same time. Your `find` won't work because the `checkbox` is a sibling of the text `input`, not a child. Try this:

```
$('input[name="name2"][type="checkbox"]').prop("disabled");
```

Note that this will be very slow in performance. A better solution is to use a `class` or `id` attribute on the checkbox itself and select by that. Also, you should use `prop` to retrieve properties of an element.

Finally, if you want to set the `disabled` property, you need to provide a second parameter to the `prop` method:

```
$('input[name="name2"][type="checkbox"]').prop("disabled", true); // disables the element
```

Answer (score 1):

`find()` selects elements descending of the matched element.

Here, checkboxes and input boxes are siblings.

Try:

```
$('input[type="text"][name="name2"]').next().attr("disabled","disabled");
```

OR

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="name2"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
```